# How to redirect all http traffic to Burp Suite?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, security, iptables, http

How to redirect all HTTP requests to Burb Suite?

I am using a Ubuntu OS running on VM installed on my macOS machine, and I have tried the following IPTables commands to do that, without success:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s5 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Please show me how to could I achieve that.

Thank you.

Comment: Is BurpSuite running inside guest VM or running on host machine?

Comment: BurpSuite is running on VM

Comment: I had the same issue in the past, where I wanted to proxy all traffic from host machine through guest VM. Routing loop was an issue. I suggest that you have two guest VMs. One will act as a client and and the other as a proxy. Host machine will handle the routing perfectly.